# Can Cucumber Framework manages codedUI automation through COM

Tags: c#, user-interface, dll, cucumber, coded-ui-tests

I am working on a BDD project using Cucumber as the Automation Framework. My Automation is done by Coded UI, which produce a dll file.

Current integration:   Cucumber will call codedUI by mstest.exe testcontainter:"c:/...*/*.dll"

The problem with this approach is that the performance. Every CodedUI call will start a DOS execution.

Question: Is it possible to treat the codedUI DLL as a COM object, such that Cucumber only needs to gave one codedUI.dll and call codedUI.automations without starting mstests.exe multiple time.

In another words, can we treat CodedUI as autoItUI.